# Android RSS parsing too slow - doing something wrong?

Tags: android, xml, performance, parsing

I followed a tutorial on how to parse XML(RSS) files on an Android app.  Below is my code that is working, but is taking quite long.  Am I doing something incorrect or in a way that would slow it down?  It takes 7-10 seconds to load 30-35 articles... seemingly way too long, and certainly too long for a user to wait every time they switch sections (which pulls in another feed)

I do have things in place to only pull new data every hour...etc ... but the first time still takes 10 seconds usually, which - by then, the user thinks their app has crashed...etc.

- I am doing this in an AsyncTask
- I'm not downloading the images at this point
- This IS the slow part of the code (not internet, or displaying... etc)

**TLDR:**
This code is too slow - why?:

```
package com.mysite.utilities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler
{

    // creats a news item class to hold data within loop
    public class NewsItem
    {
        public String title;
        public String subhead;
        public String link;
        public String byline;
        public String description;
        public String storytext;
        public String cmsstoryid;
        public String pubDate;
        public String keyword;
        public String category;
        public String subcategory;
        public String slotreference;
        public String lastModTime;
        public ArrayList<PhotoItem> photos = new ArrayList<PhotoItem>();

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return title;
        }
    }

    //creates a photo item class to hold image data within loop
    public class PhotoItem
    {
        public String photoid; //tribs id
        public String caption;
        public String height;
        public String width;
        public String photo; //full path to photo
        public String thumbnail; //full path to thumbnail
        public int articleid;
        public String photolastmodified;

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return photo;
        }
    }

    //creates instances of classes to be used in loop
    private StringBuffer buf; //to hold element characters with loop
    private ArrayList<NewsItem> feedItems;
    private NewsItem item;
    private PhotoItem photoitem;

    //initialize variables of whether or not it's within an item (or photo item)
    private boolean inItem = false;
    private boolean inPhotoItem = false;

    //
    public ArrayList<NewsItem> getParsedItems() {
        return feedItems;
    }

    //Called at the head of each new element
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts)
    {
        //creates an array of news items
        if ("channel".equals(name))
        {
            feedItems = new ArrayList<NewsItem>();
        }
        //creates a news item and toggles "in news item" to on
        else if ("item".equals(name))
        {
            item = new NewsItem();
            inItem = true;
        }
        //creates a photo item and toggles "in photo item" to on
        else if ("image".equals(name))
        {
            photoitem = new PhotoItem();
            inPhotoItem = true;
        }
        //starts a new string buffer if matches an elemnt we want from news item
        else if (
            ("title".equals(name) ||
            "subhead".equals(name) ||
            "link".equals(name) ||
            "byline".equals(name) ||
            "description".equals(name) ||
            "storytext".equals(name) ||
            "keyword".equals(name) ||
            "cmsstoryid".equals(name) ||
            "pubDate".equals(name) ||
            "category".equals(name) ||
            "subcategory".equals(name) ||
            "lastModTime".equals(name) ||
            "slotreference".equals(name)
            )
            && inItem)
        {
            buf = new StringBuffer();
        }
        //starts an a new string buffer if it matches an element we want from image item
        else if(
            ("caption".equals(name) ||
            "photoid".equals(name) ||
            "height".equals(name) ||
            "width".equals(name) ||
            "photo".equals(name) ||
            "photolastmodified".equals(name) ||
            "thumbnail".equals(name)
            )
            && inPhotoItem)
        {
            buf = new StringBuffer();
        }
    }

    //Called at the tail of each element end
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String name, String qName)
    {       
        if ("item".equals(name))
        {
            feedItems.add(item);
            inItem = false;
        }
        else if ("image".equals(name))
        {
            try {
                item.photos.add(photoitem);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            inPhotoItem = false;
        }
        else if (inItem)
        {
            if (inPhotoItem)
            {
                if ("caption".equals(name)) { photoitem.caption = buf.toString(); }
                else if ("photoid".equals(name)) { photoitem.photoid = buf.toString(); }
                else if ("height".equals(name)) { photoitem.height = buf.toString(); }
                else if ("width".equals(name)) { photoitem.width = buf.toString(); }
                else if ("photo".equals(name)) { photoitem.photo = buf.toString(); }
                else if ("photolastmodified".equals(name)) { photoitem.photolastmodified = buf.toString(); }
                else if ("thumbnail".equals(name)) { photoitem.thumbnail = buf.toString(); }
            }
            else if ("title".equals(name)) { item.title = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("subhead".equals(name)) { item.subhead = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("link".equals(name)) { item.link = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("byline".equals(name)) { item.byline = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("description".equals(name)) { item.description = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("storytext".equals(name)) { item.storytext = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("keyword".equals(name)) { item.keyword = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("cmsstoryid".equals(name)) { item.cmsstoryid = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("pubDate".equals(name)) { item.pubDate = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("category".equals(name)) { item.category = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("subcategory".equals(name)) { item.subcategory = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("lastModTime".equals(name)) { item.lastModTime = buf.toString(); }
            else if ("slotreference".equals(name)) { item.slotreference = buf.toString(); }

        }
        else
        {
            buf = null;
        }

    }

    //Called with character data inside elements
    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
    {
        //Don't bother if buffer isn't initialized
        if(buf != null)
        {
            for (int i=start; i<start+length; i++)
            {
                buf.append(ch[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**My updated code thus far (still no speed increase):**

```
package com.sltrib.utilities;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.util.Log;

public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler
{

    // creats a news item class to hold data within loop
    public class NewsItem
    {
        public String title;
        public String subhead;
        public String link;
        public String byline;
        public String description;
        public String storytext;
        public String cmsstoryid;
        public String pubDate;
        public String keyword;
        public String category;
        public String subcategory;
        public String slotreference;
        public String lastModTime;
        public ArrayList<PhotoItem> photos = new ArrayList<PhotoItem>();

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return title;
        }
    }

    //creates a photo item class to hold image data within loop
    public class PhotoItem
    {
        public String photoid; //tribs id
        public String caption;
        public String height;
        public String width;
        public String photo; //full path to photo
        public String thumbnail; //full path to thumbnail
        public int articleid;
        public String photolastmodified;

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return photo;
        }
    }

    //creates instances of classes to be used in loop
    private StringBuilder buf; //to hold element characters with loop
    private ArrayList<NewsItem> feedItems;
    private NewsItem item;
    private PhotoItem photoitem;

    //initialize variables of whether or not it's within an item (or photo item)
    private boolean inItem = false;

    private int currentTagId = 0;

    //
    public ArrayList<NewsItem> getParsedItems() {
        return feedItems;
    }


    @Override
    public void startDocument()
    {
        feedItems = new ArrayList<NewsItem>(); //creates an array to hold feed items
    }


    //Called at the head of each new element
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String name, String qName, Attributes atts)
    {
        //gets the id of the current tag
        currentTagId = 0;
        String tmpId = atts.getValue("id");
        if(tmpId != null)
        {
            currentTagId = Integer.parseInt(tmpId);
        }

        //creates a news item
        if (currentTagId == 99) // <item>
        {
            item = new NewsItem();
            inItem = true;
        }

        //creates a photo item
        else if (currentTagId == 21) { // <image>
            photoitem = new PhotoItem();
        }

        //creates a string builder if it's a tag within an article or a photo
        else if (inItem && currentTagId > 0 && currentTagId < 29)
        {
            buf = new StringBuilder();
        }
    }


    //Called at the tail of each element end
    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String name, String qName)
    {

        // it's not getting the tag id - how?

        Log.d("XML", "endElement:" + Integer.toString(currentTagId));

        if (currentTagId == 99)  // </item>
        {
            Log.d("XML", "Should be adding item: " + item.title);
            feedItems.add(item);
            inItem=false;
        }

        else if (currentTagId == 21) // </image>
        {
            try {
                item.photos.add(photoitem);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch(currentTagId)
            {
                case 1: item.title = buf.toString(); break;
                case 2: item.subhead = buf.toString(); break;
                case 3: item.link = buf.toString(); break;
                case 4: item.byline = buf.toString(); break;
                case 5: item.description = buf.toString(); break;
                case 6: item.storytext = buf.toString(); break;
                case 11: item.cmsstoryid = buf.toString(); break;
                case 14: item.pubDate = buf.toString(); break;
                case 15: item.lastModTime = buf.toString(); break;
                case 16: item.keyword = buf.toString(); break;
                case 17: item.category = buf.toString(); break;
                case 18: item.subcategory = buf.toString(); break;
                case 19: item.slotreference = buf.toString(); break;
                case 22: photoitem.caption = buf.toString(); break;
                case 23: photoitem.photoid = buf.toString(); break;
                case 24: photoitem.photolastmodified = buf.toString(); break;
                case 25: photoitem.height = buf.toString(); break;
                case 26: photoitem.width = buf.toString(); break;
                case 27: photoitem.photo = buf.toString(); break;
                case 28: photoitem.thumbnail = buf.toString(); break;
                default: if(!inItem) buf = null;
            }
        }
    }

    //Called with character data inside elements
    @Override
    public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length)
    {
        if(buf != null)
        {
            String chars = new String(ch, start, length); // get all text value inside the element tag
            chars = chars.trim(); // remove all white-space characters
            buf.append(chars);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Place in some trace calls to measure what part is taking what time. Then output the result to your GUI to see. It may the internet that's slow. It may be the rendering itself. It may be the parsing. Etc.

Comment: It's the parsing itself (the code included) that's taking long.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you are already doing this, but I just wanted to reiterate that this should be done on another thread. The user wont think the app has crashed if you display a progress indicator (spinner) and keep the GUI responsive.

If you are not doing this on a background thread, it could be making this artificially slow because the system is fighting to keep the user interface going.

As to why this is slow, there is a TON of branching. The more if statements you have, and the more elses (etc) you have, the more difficult it is for the branch predictor do do its job.

Also, I can't tell if you are downloading the images here, but if you are, that should be done asynchronously after the text data is retrieved and displayed to the user (to make the user interface more responsive).

Comment: This definitely seems like the most plausible answer. It is possible that you just have a very long feed to parse, but the mentioned optimisations should greatly improve the parse time. Also try replacing your StringBuffer with a StringBuilder. StringBuilder has several performance optimisations over StringBuffer

Comment: mtmurdock - I understand IF blocks make it slower - but do I have an option to do anything other than this?  I've edited my answer to point out that I AM using another thread, I'm not downloading the images, and I do have a progress indicator.

Comment: It looks like you are using a single handler to parse every item. I would do one of two things: leverage an xml (or whatever) parser and pass elements off to different handlers (reducing the number of branches). OR I would find some way to not do so many string compares. If you were able to convert all your strings to unique integers, the comparison would go faster (string comparison is slow).

Comment: mtmurdock - so just change `<title>` to `<0>` ...etc?  Won't I still have to do Integer.toString() or something then compare, or... what's best way to compare?

Comment: No, I mean before you start parsing, iterate over the elements and assign each one a number. This will look a lot like your current code (if ("somestring".equals(name))) but it will ultimately result in fewer string compares and more int compares. You will have to add an ID field to the xml element object so you can give them a number (if it does not already have this).

Comment: StringBuilder made no difference - everything works, but also takes the same amount of time.

Comment: Also, If you can convert your element names to integers, you can use a switch statement (which is optimized over if/else statements)

Comment: mtmurdock - so the better way WOULD be to change `<title>` to `<0>` ...etc?  Wouldn't I still need to do Integer.toString() or something?  (I'm still trying to understand what you wrote in your previous comment)

Comment: rather than changing <title> to <0>, try <title id="0">. I think your xml should still be human readable, but by having a numeric value you can greatly increase the speed of your comparisons.

Comment: How can I get the id attribute in the endElement method?  (I'm getting it in the startElement, but need it also in the end element).  I've added my updated code w/ integer/id attempt, but still no speed increase (and non-functional, as it's never adding anything, since it doesn't have an ID in endElement)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the classes you're using, but I imagine you can use the uri to look up that element in the document, and there should be some api call to read the attributes from there.

Comment: mtmurdock - it doesn't appear possible - I've asked the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724280/how-to-get-attribute-in-android-sax-helpers-defaulthandler-endelement) but no answers.  Which makes it not work using ids/integers (though I don't think it was increasing the speed anyway unfortunately)

Comment: I promise you there is a way, and if there isn't you should be using a different xml parsing library. All of this discussion aside, your performance issue is absolutely a result of too much branching and string comparisons.